# NSIS - Skip certain dialogs using command-line arguments?

Tags: dialog, installation, nsis, silent-installer, unattended-processing

Is there a way to make the NSIS installer skip certain dialogs?

It has these command-line arguments,

`/S`, `/NCRC` and `/D=dir`

Although `/S` and `/NCRC` can used for silent and unattended modes, is there are command-line arguments to make the installer skip certain dialogs in the installer and show the rest of the dialog? For example. skip the Welcome dialog and the next two dialogs and go to the fourth one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/S, /NCRC and /D= are the only installer parameters with built-in support, anything else you have to handle yourself.

[Pages can be skipped](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Skipping_Pages) by calling `Abort` in the page pre callback. It is also possible to [jump forward a specific number of pages](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Go_to_a_NSIS_page). The `GetOptions` macro can be used to parse the command line.

```
OutFile Test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user
InstallDir $Temp

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

Page License LicPre
Page Components CmpPre
Page Directory "" DiShow
Page InstFiles

Var SkippedL
Var SkippedC

!macro AbortIfCmdlineParam Switch Var
${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $0 "${Switch}" $0
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    ${If} ${Var} = 0
        StrCpy ${Var} 1
        Abort
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
!macroend

Function LicPre
!insertmacro AbortIfCmdlineParam "/SkipL" $SkippedL
FunctionEnd

Function CmpPre
!insertmacro AbortIfCmdlineParam "/SkipC" $SkippedC
FunctionEnd

Function DiShow
# Disable back button if both pages skipped, this is optional
${If} $SkippedL <> 0
${AndIf} $SkippedC <> 0
    GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 3
    EnableWindow $0 0
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

Run as `Test /SkipL /SkipC` to skip both.

Or:

```
OutFile Test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user
InstallDir $Temp

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

Page License "" LicShow
Page Components
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Function LicShow
Var /Global HasSkipped
${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $0 "/Skip=" $0
${IfNot} ${Errors}
${AndIf} $0 < 4 ; Don't let user skip InstFiles
${AndIf} $HasSkipped = 0
    StrCpy $HasSkipped 1
    SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 $0 ""
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd


Section
SectionEnd
```

...and run as `Test /Skip=2`.